# MS Word 2007 keyboard shortcut for switching between word documents

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007

I am using MS Word 2007 in the regime when all documents are in a single window (this is what I prefer right now). But now it is little clumsy to switch between the documents. I have to go to "View" tab, click the icon and select the document. This is too complicated.

Is there any easier way to switch between documents? I have tried to go through the [keyboard shortcuts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-Microsoft-Office-Word-628621ea-c0b7-4f01-bc3e-50640c0b46dc?CTT=1&CorrelationId=c18d3c30-4b8b-4ae2-a807-14c4a84fef85&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) but with no result.

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there any easier way to switch between documents?

> **Display and use Windows in Office 2007**
>
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>   When more than one window is open, switch to the next window.
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>  Switch to the previous window.

Source [Office 2007 Shortcuts](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Office_2007.html)

Comment: Thanks. Ctrl-(Shift)-F6 is almost there... but... this way i have no control over what is the next/previous document. So is there 1) something that would allow me to choose the document from the list? 2) some shortcut that would switch to the previous window but not in the sense of some fixed order, but in the sense of "previously used document"? Thanks!

Comment: 1) Not that I know of 2) <alt>+<shift>+<tab>?

Comment: Alt(shift)tab and (Shift)F6 doesn't answer the question (I have a single window Word, it is specified in the question). These are different shortcuts.

Comment: Then I think you are out of luck.

Comment: :-( unless someone else comes up with some trick ...